# Could not cast value of type Swift.UInt to Swift.UInt

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to write a small Swift program to read a MySQL database using [MySqlSwiftNative](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MySqlSwiftNative) version 1.0.10. I'm using Swift 3.0.2 and I've run into an issue downcasting the Dictionary value.

```
if let results = try query.readAllRows() {
    for row in results[0] {
        if let id = row["id"] { // as? UInt {
            print(id as! UInt)
        }
    }
}
```

`row` is a `Dictionary<String, Any>`, debugger output:

[image]

The print statement produces the following error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.UInt' (0x100be8340) to
>   'Swift.UInt' (0x1003ac960)

Why would this fail?

Update:

I added a print statement to the [MySQLDriver function](https://github.com/mcorega/MySqlSwiftNative/blob/master/Sources/MySQLDriver/Result.swift#L170) `func readAllRows() throws -> [ResultSet]?` just before the ResultSet array is returned.

```
for row in arr[0] {
    if let id = row["id"] {
        print("\(id) \(type(of: id))")
    }
}
```

This outputs

> 1 UInt

Looks good. So I modified my code to print the same thing.

```
if let results = try query.readAllRows() {
    for row in results[0] {
        if let id = row["id"] { // as? UInt {
            print("\(id) \(type(of: id))")
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

> UInt(_value: (Opaque Value)) UInt

So this may explain why the cast fails, but why am I getting this Opaque Value in the return from `readAllRows()`?

Comment: Highly mysterious. When we figure this out we're all going to feel like idiots, I just know it...

Comment: @matt lol .. yeah

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the library might be on a different version of Swift (3.0?) than your app. You might need to recompile MySqlSwiftNative using your latest version of Xcode and Swift.

Comment: I downloaded the [project from GitHub](https://github.com/mcorega/MySqlSwiftNative) and dragged MySQLDriver.xcodeproj into my Xcode project. I'm not using Cocoapods.